# Are questions related to unreleased hardware OK?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-scope

Questions on unreleased hardware like the Apple Watch. Can we questions about the features of the product and it's working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some discussion on whether to formally extend the prohibition on pre-release topics to explicitly include hardware - so at the moment it's not spelled out in the [help] for the main site.

That being said, questions speculating on Apple's future plans in general are closed as off-topic even without a pre-release hardware clause.

If you have a specific question, you can ask that here / expand on the question here by editing in what you are asking for more detailed feedback.

- [Is there support to widen the pre-release prohibition?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/is-there-support-to-widen-the-pre-release-prohibition)

You could also answer / extend the discussion there on what sort of questions you feel would be beneficial to the site.

Comment: What about questions like this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147656/what-evidence-is-there-that-the-apple-watch-is-half-the-volume-of-the-moto-360

Comment: @JashJacob unless there's credible source for the dimensions, no. It's speculative and off topic because of that. Edit: now it's closed. :)

Comment: @JashJacob Excellent discussion point. That question fails mostly at the guideline of "Focus on questions about an **actual problem** you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." In this case, the OP didn't provide what problem is to be solved so the question should probably be closed on those grounds alone. Let's presume there is an _actual problem_ to be solved. I would be willing to allow it to stay open to see if there were authoritative answers...

Comment: - even ones based on the 3000 people that have had a chance to physically measure and report on the pre-release sizes. However, we would want to be very clear, that there's no guarantee the specs won't change. Apple is very clear listing dimensions down to the mm at http://www.apple.com/watch/apple-watch/ so I don't see a problem with someone calculating the size based on clear photographs of the prototypes by Apple.